# Is it legal republish any article with Credits and Canonical Link?

Tags: canonical-url, legal

Is it legal republish any article with Credits and Canonical Link?

After the end of the post I will mention a note like Originally published at `www.example.com/post`.

Additionally I will add a `canonical` tag too that post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No it is not legal.  It is copyright infringement to copy and republish any article without the proper license to do so.  Noting the source and adding a canonical does not in any way limit your legal liability.

It sounds like you want to republish all articles as if they were licensed under the [Creative Commons attribution license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/us/).   Content that is published with that license is free to share as long as the original work is attributed.   Unless the content that you are copying is specifically labeled as being licensed with "CC BY 3.0 US" or some other similar license that permits copying, you could be sued for copyright infringement.

Note that all posts here on this site are licensed this way.  You can copy any question or answer from this site and republish it as long as you give the proper attribution.   The bottom right corner of this page (and all pages on this site), give you this information as well as link to a blog posts explaining exactly what type of attribution is needed.  For this site, you would need show that it is from StackExchange, show the author's name and link to both the post and the author page.

Note that my answer is written from the perspective of US laws.    Laws in your own country may be somewhat different, but I believe that global treaties mean that most countries treat copyrights in very similar ways.